# Python __ror__ without initializing class

Tags: python

I am using the ipython shell a lot, and decided to make some tidies wrapper function more easy to type. Goal is to be able to type `AnObject | dump`, instead of `dump(AnObject)`. This is only inside an ipython shell, and in dev. To make it easier to type.

I have come up with this so far:

```
class _dump:
    def __ror__(_, obj):
        print(obj)
dump = _dump()
d = {'test': 123}
d | dump
```

which outputs `{'test': 123}`

A tiny thing annoys me.. Is there any way to do this without initializing the class after the definition? And as a bonus, is it possible to accept both the `| dump` style, as well as, as a function (`| dump(opt=True)`)

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "as a function (`| dump(opt=True)`)" ? What is `dump` here?

Comment: I was thinking about calling the class as a function, maybe using `__call__`. So it can support to be called both as `| dump` and as a function, with parameters. Maybe this is possible with your answer below using a metaclass

Comment: it should be possible but you should be careful with overriding `__call__` or you won't be able to create `Foo` instances.

Comment: yea, thanks for the heads-up. I'm trying to get it to work, but I can't find a way to access the piped object from within the `__call__` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _dump:
    def __init__(self, opt=False):
        self.opt = opt
    def __ror__(self, obj):
        if self.opt:
            print("Opt is TRUE!")
        print(obj)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return _dump(*args, **kwds)

dump = _dump()

>>> 'a' | dump 
a
>>> 'a' | dump(opt=True)
Opt is TRUE!
a
```

Comment: Very nice! Can you explain it? __call__ is called first, then return itself. But I feel like the new call should loose the information that it should call __ror__..

Comment: `dump` is an instance of `_dump` that has `self.opt` defined as `False`, but `__call__` is returning another instance of `_dump` with `self.opt` defined to `True`. Then python calls `__ror__` on that freshly created and returned instance.

Comment: Ahh, yea.. of corse :) Thanks! Great solution

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use a metaclass then yes, it is possible:

```
class ror(type):
     @classmethod
     def __ror__(cls, obj):
         print(obj)

class Foo(metaclass=ror):
    pass

'a' | Foo

#  a
```